# Remove lines that contain number between two underscores

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to remove the lines of a richtextbox that contains a number between two underscores.

On the richtextbox, I have the following values (examples):

```
Z_OBJECTS
Z_1_OBJECTS
Z_DEBUG
Z_1_DEBUG
Z_2_DEBUG
Z_TI_PROJECTS
Z_1_TI_PROJECTS
```

I want to keep only the lines `Z_OBJECT`, `Z_TI_PROJECTS` and `Z_DEBUG`, removing the lines that contains `1_`, etc.

I'm using this function here, which works fine, but I think Regex would be better:

```
int total = 22;
for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++)
{
    List<string> finalLines = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList();
    finalLines.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith("Z_" + i + "_"));
    richTextBox1.Lines = finalLines.ToArray();
}
```

What I got in Regex is this:

```
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, @"^Z_\d*_", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Which will not remove the rest of the line.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply extend the match for the rest of the line:

```
@"^Z_\d+_.*$"
```

And I think it's better if you use `\d+` (or `[0-9]+`), since you're explicitly looking for numbers between underscores.

Comment: Any reason you use .* instead of \w*   ?

Comment: @user1189566 You never know what symbol there might be after that last underscore.